# How do I use the /setblock command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Can someone please explain the `/setblock` command?

I want a command block to set a block if there is clay but not set a block if there is black wool. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for setblock is as follows:

`/setblock <x> <y> <z> <blockName>`

The setblock command can only be used for one block at a time. It cannot replace that block based on what it previously was.

Since your situation requires you to (presumably) fill more than one block, the `/fill` command would be more appropriate.

The syntax for filling only blocks of a certain type is as follows:

`/fill [x1] [y1] [z1] [x2] [y2] [z2] [BlockToFill] 0 replace [BlockToBeReplaced]`

So to replace all clay in the world, you would use this command:

`/fill [x1] [y1] [z1] [x2] [y2] [z2] [BlockToFill] 0 replace minecraft:clay`

Simply replace the `x` `y` `z` `x2` `y2` `z2` values with the co-ordinates to fill, and `[BlockToFill]` with the ID of the block you wish to replace the clay with.

Comment: Might be worth noting that the 0 in your fill commands is the dataValue (damage value) of the block you set, which is important for filling with logs or wool.

Comment: ... until Minecraft 1.13, where that data value is removed, and logs and wool are entirely separate blocks.